# PHP url validation false positives

Tags: php, regex, validation

For some odd reason my if statement to check the urls using FILTER_VALIDATE_URL is returning unexpected results.

Simple stuff like https://www.google.nl/ is being blocked but www.google.nl/ isn't? Its not like it blocks every single URL with http or https infront of it either. Some are allowed and others are not, I know there are a bunch of topics for this but most of them are using regex to filter urls. Is this beter than using FILTER_VALIDATE_URL? Or Am I doing something wrong?

The code I use to check the URLS is this

```
if (!filter_var($linkinput, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === FALSE) {
    //error code
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `=== FALSE` there? Check for string length instead. Concretize a few more examples on which it failed. (And btw, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL is itself a regexp.)

Comment: FILTER_VALIDATE_URL has [a lot of problems](https://bugs.php.net/search.php?cmd=display&search_for=FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) that need fixing. Also, the [docs describing the flags](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) do not reflect the [actual source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/filter/logical_filters.c#L517) where references to some flags have been removed entirely.  More info here: http://news.php.net/php.internals/99018

Answer (score 0):

You should filter it like this first.  (Just for good measure).

```
$url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
```

The FILTER_VALIDATE_URL only accepts ASCII URL's (ie, need to be encoded).   If the above function does not work see PHP [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to encode the URL.

If **THAT** doesn't work, then you should manually strip the http: from the beginning like this ...

```
$url = strpos($url, 'http://') === 0 ? substr($url, 7) : $url;
```

Here are some flags that might help.  If  **all** of your URL's will have `http://` you can use **FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED**

> ***The FILTER_VALIDATE_URL filter validates a URL.***
>
> > Possible  flags:
>
> - FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED - URL must be RFC compliant (like    http://example)
> - FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED - URL must include host    name (like http://www.example.com)
> - FILTER_FLAG_PATH_REQUIRED - URL    must have a path after the domain name (like    www.example.com/example1/)
> - FILTER_FLAG_QUERY_REQUIRED - URL must have    a query string (like "example.php?name=Peter&age=37")
>
> ***The default behavior of FILTER_VALIDATE_URL***
>
> - Validates value as URL (according to »
>     http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2396), optionally with required
>     components.
> - Beware a valid URL may not specify the HTTP protocol
>     http:// so further validation may be required to determine the URL
>     uses an expected protocol, e.g. ssh:// or mailto:.
> - ***Note that the
>     function will only find ASCII URLs to be valid***; internationalized
>     domain names (containing non-ASCII characters) will fail.

Comment: FILTER_VALIDATE_URL has [a lot of problems](https://bugs.php.net/search.php?cmd=display&search_for=FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) that need fixing. Also, the [docs describing the flags](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) do not reflect the [actual source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/filter/logical_filters.c#L517) where references to some flags have been removed entirely.  More info here: http://news.php.net/php.internals/99018